# Do I Need to Persist ios/build/Builld/* for my react-native repository

Tags: ios, react-native

I am building a react-native app and when I run `git status` I see tons of unstaged items under `{path-to-app/ios/build/Build/*` do I need these or can I delete them locally and add this path to my `.gitignore`?

Answer (score 0):

Here is my default .gitignore

```
# OSX
#
.DS_Store

# Xcode
#
build/
*.pbxuser
!default.pbxuser
*.mode1v3
!default.mode1v3
*.mode2v3
!default.mode2v3
*.perspectivev3
!default.perspectivev3
xcuserdata
*.xccheckout
*.moved-aside
DerivedData
*.hmap
*.ipa
*.xcuserstate
project.xcworkspace

# Android/IJ
#
*.iml
.idea
.gradle
local.properties

# node.js
#
node_modules/
npm-debug.log

# BUCK
buck-out/
\.buckd/
android/app/libs
android/keystores/debug.keystore
```